# submitting the second drop box url javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsfiddle

I'm a bit rusty on my JavaScript.
I have a a drop down menu which has all the vehicle brands and I have all the models for each brands which have a URL link to go to.

When a brand is selected a model is comes up in the second drop down menu. Within the JavaScript there are the URL links which once submitted it should go to the desired link.

All the code is in the JS Fiddle link

```
[JS Fiddle][1]
```

Could anybody out there help me please.

Thanks in advance.

My Form Code

```
<div class="box">
<p>
    <form name="myform" class="myform">
        <select>
            <option value="">CHOOSE YOUR VEHICLE</option>
            <option value="Isuzu">Isuzu</option>
            <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
            <option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
            <option value="Mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
            <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
            <option value="VW">VW</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <br />
    <br />
    <form name="myform2" class="myform2">
        <br />
        <input type="button" name="go" value="Search" onclick="loadURL();">
    </form>
</p>
```

```
$('form[name="myform"] select').click(function () {
if ($(this).val() === 'Isuzu') {
    $('form[name=myform2] select').remove();
    $('form[name=myform2]').append('<select name="choice" onChange="document.location = this.value" value="GO">' + '<option value="http://www.direct4x4.co.uk/catalog/category/view/s/d-max-2012-onwards-canopies-hard-tops-accessories/id/17174/*_blank" >D-Max (2012 Onwards)</option>' + '</select>');
} else if ($(this).val() === 'Nissan') {
    $('form[name=myform2] select').remove();
    $('form[name=myform2]').append('<select name="choice" onChange="window.location.href=this.value">' + '<option value="http://www.direct4x4.co.uk/nissan-navara-d40-2006-onwards-canopies-hard-tops-accessories*_blank" >Navara D40 (2006 Onwards)</option>' + '</select>');
} else if ($(this).val() === 'Ford') {
    $('form[name=myform2] select').remove();
    $('form[name=myform2]').append('<select name="choice" onChange="window.location.href=this.value">' + '<option value="http://www.direct4x4.co.uk/catalog/category/view/s/ranger-t6-2012-canopies-hard-tops-onwards/id/17175/*_blank" >Ranger (T6) (2012 Onwards)</option>' + '</select>');
} else if ($(this).val() === 'Mitsubishi') {
    $('form[name=myform2] select').remove();
    $('form[name=myform2]').append('<select name="choice" onChange="jump(this.myform2)">' + '<option value="http://www.direct4x4.co.uk/catalog/category/view/s/mitsubishi-l200-2005-onwards-canopies-hard-tops-accessories/id/17178/*_blank" >L200 (2005 Onwards)</option>' + '</select>');
} else if ($(this).val() === 'Toyota') {
    $('form[name=myform2] select').remove();
    $('form[name=myform2]').append('<select name="choice" onChange="jump(this.myform2)">' + '<option value="http://www.direct4x4.co.uk/catalog/category/view/s/toyota-hilux-2005-onwards-accessories-canopies-hard-tops/id/17183/*_blank" >Hilux (2005 To 2012)</option>' + '<option value="http://www.direct4x4.co.uk/catalog/category/view/s/hilux-2012-onwards-canopies-hardtops-accessories/id/17177/*_blank" >Hilux (2012 Onwards)</option>' + '</select>');
} else if ($(this).val() === 'VW') {
    $('form[name=myform2] select').remove();
    $('form[name=myform2]').append('<select name="choice" onChange="jump(this.myform2)">' + '<option value="http://www.direct4x4.co.uk/catalog/category/view/s/volkswagen-amarok-canopies-hard-tops-accessories/id/17179/*_blank" >Amarok</option>' + '</select>');
}
```

});

EDITED Hope that helps sorry for before.

Comment: Your link does not work.

Comment: Update your post, and fix the link please.

Comment: Fixed JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/bobby316/85f3cry9/3/

(Won't let me edit the question)

Comment: Sorry about before now I've just put the code instead of JSFiddle as I think it's playing up.

Comment: It's a tad messy, but if I get it right - you want to go to different urls upon selection, correct?

Comment: @Mike86 that's correct Mike. Here's the full [link](http://sammitrcanopies.co.uk/mob/) of what the site looks like for now.

Comment: @SlashmanX Thank you for the fix much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hjbues6/1)

#### HTML

```
<div class="box">
<p>
    <form name="myform" class="myform" id="myForm">
        <select name="brand" id="select">
            <option value="">CHOOSE YOUR VEHICLE</option>
            <option value="isuzu">Isuzu</option>
            <option value="ford">Ford</option>
            <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
            <option value="mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
            <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
            <option value="vw">VW</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</p>
</div>
```

#### JS:

```
(function($) {

//your model
var urls = {
    isuzu: "https://www.direct4x4.co.uk/catalog/category/view/s/d-max-2012-onwards-canopies-hard-tops-accessories/id/17174/*_blank",
    ford: "https://www.direct4x4.co.uk/catalog/category/view/s/ranger-t6-2012-canopies-hard-tops-onwards/id/17175/*_blank",
    nissan: "",
    mitsubishi: "",
    toyota: "",
    vw: "",
}

//updating the currentUrl
var currentUrl = "";

$("#select").on("change", function(e) {
    var val = $("#select").find('option:selected').attr("value");
    currentUrl = urls[val];
});

$("#myForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(currentUrl);
    window.open(currentUrl);

});

}(jQuery));
```

#### Explanation

What I'm basically doing is storing a map of urls and updating the current url on user select.

Once I trigger the submit event (clicking search), I stop its default behavior and redirect to the last updated url (from the select 'change' event')

Just update the rest of the urls in the map and it should work flawlessly.
Also, it's easier to maintain that way.

Mike.

Comment: Oh right ok I originally started it out this way, but then I had to add other models within the brand which then my rusty knowledge of JavaScript came in. Not used JavaScript in a long time since j query and all it's tutorials and learning that. But much appreciated.

Comment: Sure thing. I'm always happy to help:)

Comment: I've been doing a lot of Magento and bootstrap and php with MySql and I've gone totally rusty on my JavaScript. I need to get my head in the game again for JavaScript.